# Со всей или из всей (страны)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Нас выписывают более 900 учреждений СО (ПО, ИЗ) всей Беларуси".

Какой предлог верный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что правильным является вариант: "Нас выписывают более 900 учреждений по  всей Беларуси".

Выбор делается по центральному значению предлогов. Предлоги СО, ИЗ обозначают соединение, совместность и извлечение, удаление. В нашем случае такого значения нет, поэтому определение предмета (900 учреждений) делается по значению соответствия, которое передает предлог ПО.

Для сравнения: Предложения от компании взбудоражили тысячи людей по всей стране (эти люди оставались на своем месте). Но: В процессе съемки участвовало более полумиллиона человек со всех стран мира (эти люди собрались в одном месте).